# Invoke a salt state depending on minion role

Tags: salt-stack, mesosphere

I think I am missing something really fundamental here but I can't seem to it figure out.

I am deploying a mesosphere environment using Salt, and what I want to do is run state files depending on the minion's role.

I have seen an example [here](https://github.com/Marmelatze/saltstack-mesos-test) where they're targeting using the top.sls file, but there are very few examples I can find doing the same thing.

So if my file-structure is thus:

```
  mesos
      |_ init.sls
      |_ mesos-master.sls
      |_ mesos-slave
```

and I only want to run the `mesos-slave.sls` on a minion with the slave role, what is the best way to do this.

In my infinite wisdom I thought doing the following would work (see fundamental misunderstanding opening paragraph)

init.sls

```
add_mesosphere_apt_repo:
  pkgrepo.managed:
    - name: deb http://repos.mesosphere.io/ubuntu {{ UBUNTU_VER }} main
    - dist: {{ UBUNTU_VER }}
    - file: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mesosphere.list
    - keyid: E56151BF
    - keyserver: keyserver.ubuntu.com

{% if salt[grains.get]('role') == 'master' %}
  include:
    - .mesos-master
{% endif %}
```

but all I get here are errors of duplicate IDs.

I'm sure the answer is very simple, I just can't seem to find anything conclusive using Google.

Answer (score 1):

## Matching using grains

You can use grain data when targeting minions:

```
salt -G 'role:mesos-slave' test.ping
```

## Matching using grains in the topfile

Matching using grains in the `top.sls` can be very efficient:

```
'role:mesos-slave':
  - match: grain
  - mesos.mesos-slave
```

## Manually syncing grains

Grains are automatically synced when `state.highstate` is called. It's however possible to sync and reload them manually:

```
salt '*' saltutil.sync_grains
salt '*' saltutil.sync_all
```

## Is targeting using grains secure?

Grains can be set by users that have access to the minion configuration files on the local system, therefore grains are considers less secure than other identifiers in Salt!

**Note:** it's best practice to not use grains for matching in your pillar top file for any sensitive pillars!

## Duplicate ID's

> ... but all I get here are errors of duplicate IDs.

Salt currently checks for duplicate IDs before execution. The ID must be unique across the entire state tree. All subsequent ID declarations with the same name will be ignored.

A simple solution for this problem might to ensure each ID is unique. You could for example include the SLS file name in the ID declaration:

For the `mesos.mesos_master` you could use:

```
mesos_master:
  file.managed:
    - name: ...
    - ...
```

For the `mesos.mesos_slave` you could use:

```
mesos_slave:
  file.managed:
    - name: ...
    - ...
```

This ways you won't receive the '*duplicate ID*' errors when including and excluding other SLS files.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to go down the targeting via `top.sls` like so:

```
'roles:ms':
  - match:grain
  - mesos.mesos-slave
```